# How do I move the add to cart button beside the price?

Tags: magento2, products

How do I move the add to cart button beside the price? In the category product list.

[image]

eventually I want something like this. Where do I completely edit the layout for the product list?
[image]

Comment: its hard to answer without seeing the logic behid this page

Comment: share your source code then maybe some can answer

Comment: it's the default source code from luma theme

Comment: basic css skills.. you should learn css in particular flex and grid for your case

Comment: I know css. I found the answer myself posted below, which is changing the grid.phtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself for just tinkering around the template. I just needed to get the file "grid.phtml" and put it on my custom theme from luma. put the add to cart in the save div section as the price button. As the answers above css alone won't help it because of the reason it is on another separate div so I had to transfer both of them on the same div so that they can be edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple css, Just make the button width smaller and place it beside the price using flex properties.

Comment: this doesn't work because they're in separate divs to begin with